# Review Link in Navigation Bar shouldn't appear on Meta at 500 Rep

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, meta

I have more than 500 rep and able to review First Posts and Late Answers on the main site.

But on Meta I can't review anything yet. There are no First Posts and Late Answers review queues there. Why do I need to see the link in the top bar if there is nothing for me to review?

If I have more than 2k, I can enter suggested edits queue, but what for? On per-site metas edits can be suggested only on tags excerpts and wikis and reviewing them requires **5k**.

**So proposals are**:

- Don't show "review" link in top bar on MSO until user reaches 3k, and is able to review close and reopen votes.
- Don't show suggested edits review queue as available to user until he reaches 5k.

Comment: I don't see the point of showing the review link if that person has nothing they could review, on main or meta.

Comment: I would suggest changing the title to "Review link appearance shouldn't have the same requirements as SO", or something similar.

Comment: It's not what you say, it's how you say it. The question title, read alone, appeared to indicate that something is wrong with the review *process*, i.e. reviewers acting like children, or angry trolls. The actual precedence makes sense. There's no reason for a `review` button if you can't use any of it on MSO. I've gone ahead and updated it to accurately describe the issue.

Comment: For the record, the 500 Rep Privilege is `access to review queues` per [the priv page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues). So it is technically working as intended in access to the queue page at 500 Rep, even though this does nothing at all for MSO since everything on that page is 2K+

Comment: @Com I stated it.

Comment: @nicael I meant more that it appears that the `review` link appears as specifically due to the 500 Rep privilege. What could possibly be done is to create a second privilege that activates the `review` button fro MSO at 2k.

Comment: @Com first sentence :)